# option(<option_variable> "help string describing option" [initial value]) sets it either ON or OFF but I'm confused

Tags: cmake

I was reading all the tutorials I could find and they just basically say

```
option(<option_variable> "help string describing option" [initial value])
```

sets it either ON or OFF. What I wanna know is that if it's a `<variable>`, then why can it be only ON or OFF? why not 5? or "something"? Is it a BOOLEAN type variable? What exactly is it? Also, was the variable specified in the `option()` code supposed to be declared "beforehand" somewhere else? or is it a brand new fresh variable that was NEVER declared before?

Answer (score 1):

In CMake `option()` command relates to BOOLEAN type of the "option", which can be set by a user. The call for

```
option(<option_variable> "help string describing option" [initial value])
```

is an equivalent to a call for

```
set(<option_variable> <initial_value> CACHE BOOLEAN "help string describing option")
```

Other types of "options" include PATH, FILEPATH and STRING, see [set(CACHE)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/set.html#set-cache-entry) documentation for more info. Type affects mostly on the selector dialog in CMake GUI. So, for `option` it will be simple selector with `ON` and `OFF` values.

Call to an `option` can be treated as an assignment a value to the variable. But if a user sets this variable (via `-D` option to `cmake` executable or via CMake GUI), user-specified value will be preserved.

Usage example:

```
option(USE_FOO "Whether to use FOO functionality" OFF)
# ...

if(USE_FOO)
    # User set the option to ON. Process this setting.
else()
    # User set the option to OFF or didn't set it at all. Process this setting.
endif()
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So just to clarify, in my code, if I have option(<option_variable> "description" ON), then that does NOT necessarily mean <option variable> was declared beforehand, but rather, it was never declared and then the option() statement declared the variable for the first time. right?